# Make reference in two Excel tables in order to automate a calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in excel. My tables stands several feature values for every month (from 1-44) The tables rows stands for the several features and the table columns for the months. I want to create a new table in which I will make a summary for every 6 months. What I want is to automatically when I change the values from the first month to change the values of the second month. A simple example of my tables are: [the initial table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pAHpiMYkCT-7XGbrWOHwLw73CmJLCYXIvm4m42Y4-E/edit#gid=0) and the [summary table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12H8utiuHXNigUeTCw1XC3GElBDnILhUd_Mf7QrLvEqs/edit#gid=0)
How can automatically make reference and sum calculation in the second table?

[image]
The image is my initial table and I want to create a new table with columns the S1_15, S2_15, S1_16, S2_16, ... and the rows the same with the first table. The values of tale 2 will correspond to summary of every semester period.

Comment: You may be better off showing screen shots instead of links

Comment: You have tagged this Excel, then linked to Google Sheets. Which is it? Also, we need to know what have you researched or attempted to resolve this on your own so far.

Comment: It is the same table.  As for my research, I am just  a regular excel user, thus I am not familiar with excel processing of cells. The only thing I now is that  have to group with some way my cells in order to generate the result in the second table.

Comment: What I did was to give name of every Nx6 tables corresponding to every semester six month period.

Comment: I think you are trying to accomplish something like this:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/383395-sumifs-using-column-row-criteria.html  Give it a shot based on those tips.  If (when) you get stuck, come back here and ask for help.